# invalid multibyte string in R on Mac but not PC

Tags: r, macos

I'm working on topic modeling a historic diary.  I ran the code on my PC, and everything loaded and worked fine.  However, when my students run the exact same code on their Mac laptops they get the following error after the last line of code that I posted: invalid multibyte string 1.

```
inputDir <- "working directory"
files.v <- dir(path=inputDir, pattern="*\\.txt")
chunk.size <- 50
makeFlexTextChunks <- function(inputDir, file.name, chunk.size=50){
  text.file.path<-file.path(inputDir, file.name)
  text.lines.v <- scan(text.file.path, what = "character", sep = "\n")
  journal.v<- paste(text.lines.v, collapse = " ")
  journal.lower.v <- tolower(journal.v)
  journal.lower.l <- strsplit(journal.lower.v, "\\W")
  journal.word.v <- unlist(journal.lower.l)
  not.blanks.v <- which(journal.word.v!="")
  journal.word.v <- journal.word.v[not.blanks.v]
  x <- seq_along(journal.word.v)
  chunks.l <-split(journal.word.v, ceiling(x/chunk.size))
  if(length(chunks.l[length(chunks.l)])<=chunk.size/2){
    chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)-1]]<- c(chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)-1]],
                                   chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)]])
    chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)]] <- NULL
  }
  chunks.l <- lapply(chunks.l, paste, collapse=" ")
  chunks.df <- do.call(rbind, chunks.l)
  return(chunks.df)
}
topic.l <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(files.v)){
  chunk.m <-makeFlexTextChunks(inputDir, files.v[i], chunk.size)
  textname <- gsub("\\..*", "", files.v[i])
  segments.m <- cbind(paste(textname, segment=1:nrow(chunk.m), sep = "_"), 
chunk.m)
  topic.l[[textname]] <- c("id", "text")
 }
```

I checked and double-checked my txt files.  They are all in UTF-8 and there are no unusual characters in the files.  Why is the code working on my PC, but not on their Macs?